# Как установить начальную точку для SVG-пути

Tags: css, вёрстка, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Я работаю над анимацией загрузки.
У меня есть 3 фигуры, которые я хочу перемещать по траектории и масштабировать их по мере их движения.
3 фигуры будут следовать по одному пути, но из разных начальных точек.
Я создал формы и контуры в Illustrator и экспортировал SVG.
Вот пример самой большой формы и ее пути.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моя проблема заключается в том, что мне не хочется тратить весь день на пробы и поиск ошибок, меняя порядок точек пути.
Есть ли более простой способ установить начальную точку?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моя форма начинается с неправильной точки, как вы можете видеть на этом изображении.

Мой код:

```css
.loading-wrap {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.cir-3 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background:cornflowerblue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 30%;

    offset-path: path("M147.33,108.45A49.76,49.76,0,0,0,97.57,58.69c-22.33,0-45.32,20.86-47.52,35-1.46,4.68-2.23,19.13,61,21.5-.79,14.37-43.76,9.63-61.5,6.39a49.77,49.77,0,0,0,97.78-13.09Z");
    
    animation: move 3s ease-in-out infinite reverse;
}

@keyframes move {
    100% { 
        offset-distance: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="loading-wrap">
            <div class="cir-1"></div>
            <div class="cir-2"></div>
            <div class="cir-3"></div>
        </div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to set starting point for SVG path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62538979/7394871) от участника  [@frostbyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1876014/frostbyte).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/62538979/7394871

Comment: Обратите внимание на этот топик, так как использована **анимация CSS движения по криволинейному пути**. Раньше это можно было делать только в SVG, затем это стало возможно в Chrome и теперь это поддерживают все современные браузеры, включая Edge [Caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=motion)

Comment: лет через 15 js и smil вытеснит css скорее всего

Comment: если сафари не поддерживается то это жирный минус

Comment: @MaximLensky ну всё равно согласись, - это большой шаг вперед, раньше это было только в Chrome, а теперь нет только в Safari

Comment: конечно круто - я понимаю что это прогресс ...

Answer (score 5):

Мое решение заключается в использовании 3 разных анимаций для каждого div. Каждый div имеет различное начальное `offset-distance`, и `offset-distance` анимируется с другим значением.

```css
.loading-wrap {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  border:1px solid black;
  
  position:absolute;
}

test{position:relative;}

.test div{
  position:absolute;
  offset-path: path("M147.33,108.45A49.76,49.76,0,0,0,97.57,58.69c-22.33,0-45.32,20.86-47.52,35-1.46,4.68-2.23,19.13,61,21.5-.79,14.37-43.76,9.63-61.5,6.39a49.77,49.77,0,0,0,97.78-13.09Z");  
}

.cir-1 {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:rgb(119, 30, 30);
  animation: move 3s ease-in-out infinite;
  
}
.cir-2 {
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  offset-distance: 10%;
  animation: move2 3s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.cir-3 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:cornflowerblue;
  offset-distance: 20%;
  animation: move3 3s ease-in-out infinite;
}
@keyframes move {
  100% { 
    motion-offset: 100%;
    offset-distance: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes move2 {
  100% { 
    motion-offset: 100%;
    offset-distance: 110%;
  }
}

@keyframes move3 {
  100% { 
    motion-offset: 100%;
    offset-distance: 120%;
  }
}




svg{position:absolute;}
```

```html
<div class="loading-wrap">
<svg viewBox="-50 -50 200 200">
  <path d="M97.78,49.76a49.76,49.76,0,0,0,-49.76,-49.76c-22.33,0,-45.32,20.86,-47.52,35c-1.46,4.68,-2.23,19.13,61,21.5c-0.79,14.37,-43.76,9.63,-61.5,6.39a49.77,49.77,0,0,0,97.78,-13.09z" fill="none" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
<div class="test">
  <div class="cir-1"></div>
  <div class="cir-2"></div>
  <div class="cir-3"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [How to set starting point for SVG path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62541610/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

**Если вам нужна анимация для запуска наоборот, у вас есть 2 решения:**

1. `M97.78,49.76L97.78,49.8A49.77,49.77 0 0 10,62.89C17.74,66.13 60.71,70.87 61.5,56.5C-1.73,54.123 -0.96,39.68 0.5,35C2.7,20.86 25.69,0 48.02,0A49.76,49.76 0 0 197.78,49.76z`
   Используйте этот `path` взамен

```css
.loading-wrap {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);  
  position:absolute;
  border:1px solid silver;
}

test{position:relative;}

.test div{
  position:absolute;
  offset-path: path("M97.78,49.76L97.78,49.8A49.77,49.77 0 0 10,62.89C17.74,66.13 60.71,70.87 61.5,56.5C-1.73,54.123 -0.96,39.68 0.5,35C2.7,20.86 25.69,0 48.02,0A49.76,49.76 0 0 197.78,49.76z");  
}

.cir-1 {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:rgb(119, 30, 30);
  animation: move 3s ease-in-out infinite;
  
}
.cir-2 {
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  offset-distance: 10%;
  animation: move2 3s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.cir-3 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:cornflowerblue;
  offset-distance: 20%;
  animation: move3 3s ease-in-out infinite;
}
@keyframes move {
  100% {     
    offset-distance: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes move2 {
  100% {     
    offset-distance: 110%;
  }
}

@keyframes move3 {
  100% { 
    offset-distance: 120%;
  }
}




svg{position:absolute;}
```

```html
<div class="loading-wrap">
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path d="M97.78,49.76L97.78,49.8A49.77,49.77 0 0 10,62.89C17.74,66.13 60.71,70.87 61.5,56.5C-1.73,54.123 -0.96,39.68 0.5,35C2.7,20.86 25.69,0 48.02,0A49.76,49.76 0 0 197.78,49.76z" fill="none" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
<div class="test">
  <div class="cir-1"></div>
  <div class="cir-2"></div>
  <div class="cir-3"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

2. Вы можете использовать тот же путь, но тогда анимируйте divs с отрицательным расстояниям смещения.

```css
.loading-wrap {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  border:1px solid silver;
  
  position:absolute;
}

test{position:relative;}

.test div{
  position:absolute;
  offset-path: path("M97.78,49.76a49.76,49.76,0,0,0,-49.76,-49.76c-22.33,0,-45.32,20.86,-47.52,35c-1.46,4.68,-2.23,19.13,61,21.5c-0.79,14.37,-43.76,9.63,-61.5,6.39a49.77,49.77,0,0,0,97.78,-13.09z");  
}

.cir-1 {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:rgb(119, 30, 30);
  animation: move 3s ease-in-out infinite;
  
}
.cir-2 {
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  offset-distance: -10%;
  animation: move2 3s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.cir-3 {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:cornflowerblue;
  offset-distance: -20%;
  animation: move3 3s ease-in-out infinite;
}
@keyframes move {
  100% { 
    offset-distance: -100%;
  }
}

@keyframes move2 {
  100% { 
    offset-distance: -110%;
  }
}

@keyframes move3 {
  100% { 
    offset-distance: -120%;
  }
}

svg{position:absolute;}
```

```html
<div class="loading-wrap">
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path d="M97.78,49.76a49.76,49.76,0,0,0,-49.76,-49.76c-22.33,0,-45.32,20.86,-47.52,35c-1.46,4.68,-2.23,19.13,61,21.5c-0.79,14.37,-43.76,9.63,-61.5,6.39a49.77,49.77,0,0,0,97.78,-13.09z" fill="none" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
<div class="test">
  <div class="cir-1"></div>
  <div class="cir-2"></div>
  <div class="cir-3"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [How to set starting point for SVG path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62541610/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>